# How can I let the user name the file and type what ever he\she wants? How can I do it on vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How can I let the user name the file and type what ever he\she wants? How can I do it on vb.net?

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim path As String = "C:\Users\system call\khaled.txt"

        ' Create or overwrite the file.
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)

        ' Add text to the file.
        Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.")
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
        fs.Close()
       
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I fixed your code formatting once and it seems that you deleted that question and posted the same badly formatted code. This site provides a preview for a reason. Don't submit a question or an answer if your code is not formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to let the User save the Data as he wants and where he wants?
Than maybe this could be helpfull

```
        Dim myStream As Stream
    Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog
    Dim path As String
    saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".xml"
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "XML files(.xml)|*.xml|all Files(*.*)|*.*"
    saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "desktop"
    If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        myStream.Close()
    End If
    path = saveFileDialog1.FileName
```

You can Change the Default Values to what you want, like

```
saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".txt"
```

You need to import System.IO